# Get post type on edit page

Tags: custom-post-types

I am writing the backend for my theme and have 4 custom post types. I have registered them all and now I am writing the metaboxes and handlers.

My question is: in WordPress admin, is there a way of determining which custom post type you're editing? i.e. lets say I have a custom post type of `Testimonials`, I click <kbd>Add New</kbd> and am presented with various fields. Is there a function in WordPress that will tell me what this post type is?

I've tried `get_post_type()`, but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 8):

There are hooks and variables set that will allow you determine post type pretty easily, so you can hook onto actions specific to a given type, i'm going to provide some examples below.

## Examples

If wanted to add a metabox to the post creation screen for the `book` post type, then i'd probably use a hook along the lines of..

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_book', 'my_callback_defining_metaboxes' );
function my_callback_defining_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box( ... );
}
```

You can replace `book` with an appropriate post type, eg. post, page, or a custom one.

If i wanted to enqueue scripts onto the edit or add new posts screen for the book post type, i might use..

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-edit.php', 'my_func_to_enqueue_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'my_func_to_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_func_to_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $typenow;
    if( 'book' == $typenow )
        wp_enqueue_script( ... );
}
```

If i wanted to go a step further and hook onto every page that deals with the book post type i'll use a more generic hook and perform conditional logic on one of the admin variables..(as long as you don't hook in really early you can reference these vars reliably).

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_on_specific_posttype_pages' );
function enqueue_scripts_on_specific_posttype_pages() {
    global $parent_file;
    if( 'edit.php?post_type=book' == $parent_file )
        wp_enqueue_script( ... );
}
```

`$parent_file` is always the link or URL of the parent menu item for the given post type, which you'll notice is different to the generic `$hook_suffix` that's appended to the `admin_print_scripts-` hook, eg. `admin_print_scripts-edit.php` ..

The above example would hook the enqueue onto any page for the `book` post type, that includes the taxonomy management screens.

Hope the above is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The global `$current_screen->post_type` is more robust than relying on `$_GET['post_type']` or `$parent_file`.

Answer (score 3):

that's because the post hasn't been saved yet.

try with `$_GET['post_type']`

Comment: Thanks That works if I have records. What if I click on Add New, is there a way then of determining the post type.

Comment: Just answered my own question post_type is a query string value on add new and id is a value on editing. I can assotain what the value is from both of them.

Comment: that works if you don't have records too

Comment: That's not true. The post has been created since it is a new record on db but in draft state. Infact you can get the ID of that post type.

Comment: I don't think this works as of wp 5.0

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get info about the current screen you can but depend in which hook you are working.

For example, have a look at:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function () {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    var_dump($screen);

    var_dump(get_the_ID());
});
```

When you click on **Add New** and during the **add_meta_boxes** is executed you can retrieve the current screen (please don't use global variables) and also the new ID of the post that is currently in **Draft** state.

Answer (score 1):

Let's close this storry. I create function for solving this problem and you can use it how you want. It is ment for the wp-admin part but you can expand it.

```
function wp_admin_post_type () {
    global $post, $parent_file, $typenow, $current_screen, $pagenow;

    $post_type = NULL;

    if($post && (property_exists($post, 'post_type') || method_exists($post, 'post_type')))
        $post_type = $post->post_type;

    if(empty($post_type) && !empty($current_screen) && (property_exists($current_screen, 'post_type') || method_exists($current_screen, 'post_type')) && !empty($current_screen->post_type))
        $post_type = $current_screen->post_type;

    if(empty($post_type) && !empty($typenow))
        $post_type = $typenow;

    if(empty($post_type) && function_exists('get_current_screen'))
        $post_type = get_current_screen();

    if(empty($post_type) && isset($_REQUEST['post']) && !empty($_REQUEST['post']) && function_exists('get_post_type') && $get_post_type = get_post_type((int)$_REQUEST['post']))
        $post_type = $get_post_type;

    if(empty($post_type) && isset($_REQUEST['post_type']) && !empty($_REQUEST['post_type']))
        $post_type = sanitize_key($_REQUEST['post_type']);

    if(empty($post_type) && 'edit.php' == $pagenow)
        $post_type = 'post';

    return $post_type;
}
```

In the general this will give you the most accurate post type information inside WordPress Admin side.

Enjoj!

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress block editor, inside `enqueue_block_assets` hook, you can use `get_post_type()` function and enqueue appropriate scripts/styles.