# Why are admin scripts not printed 

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to enqueue/print scripts in the admin area. But they dont seem to appear.

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    add_meta_box('portfolio-meta', 'Details', 'portfolio_metabox_details', 'portfolio');

    wp_register_script('jqeury-validate', 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate');
    wp_register_script('ae-admin', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/admin.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-validate'));
    wp_enqueue_script('ae-admin');
    wp_localize_script('ae-admin', 'WpAjax', array(
            'AjaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));
    wp_register_style('ae-validate', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/css/validate.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('ae-validate');
});
```

But my script (`admin.js`) does not seem to get printed. I even tried to put those in 'init' instead of 'admin_init' still I dont see my scripts ... why is that? How can I debug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of `admin_init`

Note: you should use hooks that target admin pages as specifically as possible. e.g.:

- **Plugins**: Use the `admin_print_scripts-{plugin-page}` hook
- **Themes**: Use the `admin_print_scripts-{theme-page}` hook (where `{theme-page}` is whatever string you use in the `add_theme_page()` call)
- **Custom Post-Type Edit Page**: Use the `admin_print_scripts-edit.php` hook,

For Custom Post Types, inside your function, do something like the following:

```
global $typenow;
if( 'portfolio' == $typenow ) {
    // wp_enqueue_script() calls go here
}
```

(h/t [t31os](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5837/custom-post-types-question/5847#5847))

Comment: Note also: if these scripts are for a particular Plugin, then you should only enqueue such scripts on admin pages **specific to your Plugin**, using the `admin_print_scripts-{plugin-page}` hook.

Comment: @Chris_O, I suppose something like http://pastie.org/2099186, it still does not work ...

Comment: @Chip Bennett, I am making a theme, the JS are for a theme options page

Comment: Ok, I just put http://pastie.org/2099209 in functions.php directly instead of in a hook and it works. But I think its wrong? Also whats wrong with it? Also why does admin_enqueue_scripts/styles not working ....

Comment: @JM at Work: the principle applies to *Themes* as well as to *Plugins*. For **Themes**, use the `admin_print_scripts-{theme-page}` hook (where `{theme-page}` is whatever string you use in the `add_theme_page()` call).

Comment: @Chip Bennett, ops, my mistake, its for a custom post type meta box actually

Comment: I also noticed that `wp_enqueue_script('jqeury-validate', 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_enqueue_script('ae-admin', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/admin.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-validate'));`. jQuery Validate will be printed but not my `admin.js`

Comment: And on what *page* will said custom post type metabox appear? On the edit post page for the custom post type? If so, use the `admin_print_scripts-edit.php`, and then inside your function, globalize $typenow, and do a conditional on `if ( $posttype == $typenow )` (where `$posttype` is the name of your custom post type).

Comment: @Chip Excellent answers!  Thanks for expanding on this.

Comment: I registered post type with `register_post_type('portfolio', array(...));`. And now used admin_print_scripts-edit.php as u mentioned. Also I added a `die()` in there but it does not seem to be run

Comment: @Chris_O I was hoping you wouldn't mind me adding those. The comment system was complaining to me about "extended discussion". :)

Comment: Erm ... `admin_print_scripts-edit.php` hook does not appear to be run, I did a `die('OK')` on line 1 and I dont see it

Comment: I fell back to `admin_print_scripts` and I found that $typenow is actually `post` even though I am editing a `portfolio`. I noticed in the HTML, I see http://pastie.org/2143755. Where postnow is portfolio. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that your `add_action()` call is incorrect. You have to pass it a *callback*, not the *function definition*.

You have:

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    // function definition here
});
```

Instead, you should have:

```
function mytheme_enqueue_admin_scripts() {
     // register/enqueue code goes here
}
add_action( 'hook_name', 'mytheme_enqueue_admin_scripts' );
```

Comment: Holly Javascript Batman! Good Catch :)

Comment: I suppose it's *possible* that an anonymous function will work there, but I've never seen it used in the wild.

Comment: Totally, Looks like it should work in PHP >= 5.3. As far as I know this goes against best practices though. I remember Nacin mentions something along these lines at WordCamp Seattle using create_function() as an example and I've since read about it not-so-good elsewhere. One reason given is that there is no way to un-hook the function.

Comment: I was using an anonymous function as I know I will be using >= PHP 5.3 and since I am only using the function once. I'll try it without anonymous functions sometime

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your header.php (or another function in the header) runs the wp_head action hook. The code should look like this:

```
<?php wp_head() ?>
```

Comment: He's enqueuing the scripts on the admin side not the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just had a typo

```
wp_register_script('jqeury-validate', 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate
                      ^
```

But thanks @Chris_O, & @Chip Bennett for their great answers